# Why are all my Delphi apps missing the taskbar menu on Windows 10 but not Windows 7?

Tags: windows, delphi, taskbar

In Windows 7 when I right click on the taskbar icon, all my Delphi apps (5, 2006 and XE) show the full taskbar menu: App name, Pin/Unpin and Close Window. On Windows 10 all these apps show only the Close Window menu item. Why is that and how can I get the full menu in Win10?

Update: If I create a new app in Delphi XE on Win 10 it shows the full menu. If I create a new app on Delphi XE in Win 7 it shows the full menu on Win 7 but not on Win 10.

Comment: My program has no such problems. Please tell us what is different with your program? How does it differ from mine?

Comment: @David Heffernan Guessing you didn't compile on Win 7.

Comment: It doesn't matter on which system you build your application.

Comment: @TLama So why the taskbar menu discrepancies in the two compiled programs?

Comment: Does this happen for a brand new empty application?

Comment: @R.Hoek That would make it hidden on both versions of Windows.

Comment: @fullerm Hmm, misspelled the property: t should be `Application.MainformOnTaskbar := true` - http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_MainFormOnTaskBar.html (the other one is `Application.ShowmainForm`, which hides it from the taskbar, when `MainformOnTaskBar = true`).

Comment: @JerryDodge no is doest: but i misspelled the property

Comment: @R.Hoek Yes both have Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True; Neither has Application.ShowmainForm; Code is identical.

Comment: The point of my original comment was to encourage you to suspect that the content of the program was important. Having a [mcve] would make it possible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @David Heffernan It happens with an empty app, a blank form with an edit box. It is not about the program content.

Comment: @fullerm Have you tried this on other Windows 10 machines? Maybe the problemlies with Win10 itself?

Comment: Is the Delphi XE the *exact* same version (incl. patches)? Are you using the *exact* same files? Try Ctrl+O O (or whatever your current keyboard setup uses) to insert all compiler directives into the .dpr and .pas file of the empty program to ensure that they are compiled with the same options.

Comment: @HeartWare I used Ctrl+O O to get all the compiler directives into the .dpr and .pas files. They are identical. I copied the code from the Win7 machine to the Win10 machine, compiled and the full menu appears.

Comment: @R.Hoek I see the same problem on every Win10 machine I've tried.

Answer (score -2):

No, this neither happens to all your apps (it happens to every application with a window), nor can *David Heffernan* be able to see it: Win10 just don't has that (most likely it was gone with Win8 already).

To make sure what *fullerm* is talking about: right-click on the task **button** and see its context menu: for every window you only have "close" plus two more generic entries, and then based on the application even more. But the **system menu** (right click on a window's top left icon) is not available thru the **task button** anymore

- **Task button** = taskbar representing each currently displayed window. Pinned apps and shortcuts are not task buttons, neither are those of the **task tray** (rightmost next to the clock)
- **System menu** = context menu every window owns with basic entries like "minimize", "maximize", "close", "size", "move" and even more. Accessible thru right clicking the topleft icon of a window or pressing ALT+SPACE. Might be inaccessible when the window is owner-drawn.
- **Window** = owned by a running **process**. Processes neither need to have a window, nor are they restricted to only having one window. Nowadays Windows calls processes "apps" (I guess).